# Volume level indicator plugin

Tags: sound, indicator

I may not be best at terminilogy but i am looking for a GNOME plugin allowing me to see the mater volume indicator in real time, like this one:

[image]

In new gnome, the "indicators" are hidden and you need to swipe your mouse down to see them. I'd like mine on the top toolbar (the bar with the clock).

Answer (score 1):

I looked and found this one in the software center.

[image: volume meter]

It is called Pulseaudio Volume Meter (Playback) It will be found on the side, but you just double click on the icon and then you can drag and drop it wherever you would like.

Comment: I like this but i was looking for indicator applet.